# É correto escrever "há-de-se-lhes perdoar"?

Tags: gramática

Estava a ler o Memorial do Convento quando me deparei com uma frase que lia "há-de-se-lhes perdoar". Que é que se está a passar nesta frase, sequer?! Eu pensei que se escrevesse "há-de se lhes perdoar", porque o "se lhes" fosse relativo ao verbo "perdoar" e não ao "haver de".

Qual é a forma correta de escrever isto e a que verbo se refere cada uma das preposições/pronomes?

Comment: Certo deve estar, mas de repente em desuso. Lembro de uma frase famosa dita pelo ex presidente do Brasil Jânio Quadros: *Fi-lo porque qui-lo.* Muitas das vezes, é apenas uma construção erudita. http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/fi-lo-porque-qui-lo-aprenda-gramatica-com-frase-historica-de-janio-quadros.html

Comment: Esta questão só se põe em relação à grafia pré-AO90: a grafia oficial agora é *há de* e não *há-de*, e não tou a ver escrever-se *há de-se-lhes perdoar*.

Comment: Acho que deve de ser *há-de se lhes perdoar*, já que se escrevia *há-de (espaço) verbo* nel passado, sem hífen, e os pronomes átonos vão com o verbo *perdoar* e não *haver-de*

Comment: @guifa, em Portugal, há uma grande tendência a ligar os pronomes átonos ao primeiro verbo: *vou-te contar uma coisa; podes-me dizer as horas?* etc. Quando há uma preposição pelo meio, já vêm normalmente em próclise ao segundo: *tens de me contar tudo, havemos de nos encontrar;* mas com *hei de, hás de, há de* e *hão de* é mais complicado porque nós articulamos o *hei de* etc. como se fosse uma palavra só, como se *de* fosse parte do verbo; tanto que se ouve o erro *hades* (por *hás de*) e até mesmo *hadem* (por *hão de*), como se o verbo fosse *hader*.

Comment: @Jacinto isso sei, mas depois de preposições não se liga. Pensava que a ligação antiga com *de* só era porque em contraste com outras perífrases, era possível contestar acabando em preposição: *has de fazê-lo? He **de*** frente a *tens de/que fazê-lo? Tenho* (e não *tenho de/que*)

Comment: @Peixoto - a propósito, o mesmo ex-presidente também teria dito, "bebo por que é líguido; se fosse sólido, come-lo-ia. Se eu fosse presidente do Brasil, evitaria mesóclises a todo custo, aparentemente não são de bom agouro...

Comment: @guifa, não compreendi a partir de "a ligação antiga com *de* era..." Tanto dizemos *hás de fazê-lo* como *hás de o fazer*. Também me chocam o hífen à direita do *de* (*de-se*, etc.) mas escreveu-se assim de facto em Portugal.

Answer (score 6):

Com o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, já não se utiliza o hífen entre as formas monossilábicas de *haver* e *de* ([Base XVIII do Acordo](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990)). Temos agora, portanto, *há de se lhes perdoar*.

Antes de o acordo ortográfico entrar em vigor, encontram-se as duas variantes quando *haver de* é seguido de clíticos. Um par de exemplos do Google Books:

> - *Hei-de lhe* falar lugubremente (Cesário Verde, edição de 1992: [link](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mKbuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hei-de-lhe%22&dq=%22hei-de-lhe%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioxuKf6aLUAhXCuhQKHZVuBrQQ6AEIMDAC))
> - *Hei-de-lhes* acabar com a manha de andarem atrás de mim! (Branquinho da Fonseca, edição de 1945, [link](https://books.google.pt/books?id=QE8TAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Hei-de-lhes%20acabar%22&dq=%22Hei-de-lhes%20acabar%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y))

Ou no jornal Público, que não aplica o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990:

> - *Há-de-se* ver, mulher. *Há-de-se* ver. Respondia como sempre falava: *há-de-se viver* ([link](https://www.publico.pt/culturaipsilon/jornal/na-berma-de-nenhuma-estrada-126785))
> - Se acontecer, *há-de se* ver na altura ([link](https://www.publico.pt/2017/01/22/sociedade/noticia/vila-velha-do-rodao-se-almaraz-rebentar-nada-nos-safa-quando-chegar-a-noticia-ja-ca-esta-a-agua-1759047))
> - É por causa de Hollande, mas *há-de-lhes* passar. ([link](http://blogues.publico.pt/tudomenoseconomia/2017/05/05/o-centro-assanhado/))

Não é óbvio que uma variante seja muito mais comum do que a outra.

Não consegui encontrar nenhuma fonte que apontasse para a correção de uma ou de outra forma. Em todo o caso, o teu argumento para rejeitar a união com hífen («"se lhes" [é] relativo ao verbo "perdoar" e não ao "haver de"») é problemático — não é óbvio que a afirmação seja verdadadeira. Os verbos auxiliares admitem **subida de clítico**, isto é, a ligação ao verbo auxiliar do pronome clítico complemento do verbo principal.

Não há dúvida de que *haver de* admite subida do clítico em construções com próclise:

> Não *lho hei de* perdoar. (em alternativa a «Não *hei de* perdoar-lho»).

O que é extraordinário nos verbos auxiliares que regem a proposição *de* (*haver de*, *ter de*, *acabar de*), é parecerem não admitir o pronome em posição enclítica:

> **Hei-lho* de perdoar.

Nem sempre assim foi. Por exemplo:

> *Hemo-nos*, senhores, *de* ir. (Camões, [link](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A64OAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA188&dq=%22hemo-nos,+senhores%22&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hemo-nos%2C%20senhores%22&f=false))
>   *Hás-me* de jurar uma cousa que te não custará nada. (Herculano)
>   Casarás com o homem; mas já agora *hão-se* de festejar os teus dezassete anos em casa. (Camilo)

Modernamente, com as formas monossilábicas de *haver*, é inclusive pouco aceitável inserir *qualquer* elemento entre *haver* e *de* (cf. *havemos um dia de lá ir* com **hei um dia de lá ir*), daí a antiga ortografia prescrever um hífen. Mas nenhum dos auxiliares que regem *de* aceitam um pronome unido ao verbo 
auxiliar em posição enclítica (cf. *ficou-me a dever*, que não é problemático, e onde o auxiliar rege *a*). A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian, na pág. 1242 (cap. 29, da autoria de Eduardo Raposo), dá estes exemplos:

> a. ??*Tenho-lhe de pagar* alguma coisa, certamente.
>   b. *Ela *há-me de encontrar* nalgum momento.
>   c. ??O mordomo *acabou-me de trazer* o pequeno almoço.

Mas se o pronome estiver à direita de *de* (*temos de lhe pagar*, *há de me encontrar*, *acabou de me trazer*), as construções são aceitáveis. O autor sugere resolver a aparente anomalia dos auxiliares que regem *de* desta forma:

> Para resolver este paradoxo, propõe-se aqui a hipótese de que a preposição *de* se "incorpora" no verbo auxiliar, formando com ele um grupo complexo unitário do ponto de vista morfológico. Ou seja, a preposição *de* é parte integrante dos verbos auxiliares (repare-se que, antes do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, a ortografia codificava essa estrutura no caso do auxiliar *haver (de)*, ao unir os dois itens com um hífen).

No entanto, como o autor reconhece (caixa 9) e como tu sugeres, esses casos também podem ser analisados como casos de próclise ao verbo principal.

Frases como "hei de lhe dizer" seriam então estruturalemente ambíguas entre casos de próclise ao verbo pleno e ênclise ao verbo auxiliar (unido com *de*). No primeira caso, faria mais sentido escrever *há-de se lhes perdoar* (tal como os brasileiros escrevem *vou te perdoar*, sem hífen, dado que se trata de uma próclise ao verbo principal), no segundo *há-de-se-lhes*. Como referi antes, ambas podem ser encontradas.

Comment: No [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/), em autores portugueses é largamente maioritária a versão com hífenes (*há-de-se* vs. *há-de se*), enquanto em autores brasileiros raramente há hífen para ligar ao *de* (*há de* vs. *há-de*) e nunca há hífenes à direita do *de* (encontram-se alguns *há-de se*, mas não *há-de-se). Que as formas monossilábicas de *haver* + *de* são vistas, pelos portugueses, como unidade morfológica vê-se pelo erro comum *hades* (por *hás de*); também se ouve *hadem* (por *hão de*).

Answer (score 2):

Tentei enviar como comentário, mas ficou muito extenso e acabei precisando transformar em resposta para poder enviar.

No Português medieval (careço de fonte), construções do tipo *haver* (no presente ou pretérito imperfeito do indicativo) mais a proposição *de* mais o infinitivo impessoal de um verbo eram uma forma de construir os futuros do indicativo (tanto do presente, como do pretérito).

Nos verbos regulares, ainda é possível reconhecer o paralelismo entre *amarei* e *hei de amar*, *protegerás* e *hás de proteger*, *garantiriam* e *haveriam de garantir* etc.

Pensando em termos gramaticais contemporâneos, seria como se fizéssemos uma próclise da desinência verbal, como hoje ainda fazemos com os pronomes pessoais oblíquos átonos.

Assim, a expressão "há-de-se-lhes perdoar" pode ser pensada como uma próclise da desinência verbal e dos dois pronomes pessoais oblíquos átonos.

A utilização dos hífens deve ter seguido a convenção da época, anterior à era dos acordos ortográficos internacionais, mas que mantém paralelismo com a utilização de hífens na ênclise e na mesóclise. Em termos atuais, poderia ser escrita "perdoar-se-lhe-á".

Hoje em dia, o que mudou foi só a utilização dos hífens nas próclises, que caiu em desuso.

Comment: Aqui a questão parece-me um pouco diferente. Usar o *haver* para formar o futuro é corriqueiro em Portugal: "*hás de vir* cá jantar um dia destes", é normalíssimo da silva; equivale a *virás*, mas transmite mais vontade e determinação da minha parte em que venhas cá jantar. A questão está no hífenes. E o que se passa, parece-me, é que nós, portugueses, entendemos o *se-lhes* como ênclise do *haver* em vez de próclise do *perdoar*, mesmo estando a preposição *de* pelo meio.